# How Can use Execute Immediate statement be nested inside in the Execute Immediate

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamic-sql, oracle19c

I have a fixed Execute immediate narrative. The sql_text in it will only bring in one parameter to do a simple syntax query

example

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_text USING SN RETURNING INTO MSG;
```

sql_text is a search statement that can be used alternatively

```
sql_txt = 'select count(1) from productDetails  where ID = :parameter1'
```

Originally, EXECUTE IMMEDIATE would only bring in one parameter to execute sql_text. This time I want to bring in multiple parameters to execute sql_text without affecting the existing sql_text operation with only one parameter.

Therefore, many attempts have failed. The wrong SQL is as follows

```
DECLARE
    SQL_TEXT VARCHAR2(1000);
    MSG VARCHAR2(500);
    SN VARCHAR2(500) := parameter1/parameter2;
BEGIN

   sql_text := '
   DECLARE
   parameters VARCHAR2(50);
   parameter1 VARCHAR2(50);
   parameter2 VARCHAR2(50);
   sql_txt VARCHAR2(1000);
   BEGIN
      parameters := :SN;
      parameter1 := substr(parameters,0,10);
      parameter2 := substr(parameters,11,10);
      
      sql_txt = ''select count(1) from productDetails  where ID = :parameter1
      AND NUMBER = :parameter2''
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_txt USING parameter1 RETURNING INTO MSG;
   END;'; 
   
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_text USING SN RETURNING INTO MSG;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(MSG);
END;
```

I tried to put multiple parameters into one parameter.

```
SN VARCHAR2(500) := parameter1/parameter2;
```

Take out the parameters from sql_text and use

```
 parameters := :SN;
      parameter1 := substr(parameters,0,10);
      parameter2 := substr(parameters,11,10);
```

It keep trying and fail

database verson：oracle database 19c

Ask for help

Thanks

Comment: Post any error messages. Note that your string inside your inner exec immediate references variables from the SQL outside your outer.. How would that work?

Comment: The error message needs to wait until tomorrow to provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "wrong" SQL has several problems:

1. There's a semi-colon missing at the end of the assignment to `sql_text`.
2. In the same statement, `NUMBER` is not a valid identifier in Oracle unless it's quoted.
3. The initialization of `SN` needs to have apostrophes around the text.

So the assignment to `sql_text` should read

```
sql_txt := ''select count(1) from productDetails  where ID = :parameter1
          AND "NUMBER" = :parameter2'';
```

So your block should then be

```
DECLARE
    SQL_TEXT VARCHAR2(1000);
    MSG VARCHAR2(500);
    SN VARCHAR2(500) := 'parameter1/parameter2';
BEGIN

   sql_text := '
   DECLARE
   parameters VARCHAR2(50);
   parameter1 VARCHAR2(50);
   parameter2 VARCHAR2(50);
   sql_txt VARCHAR2(1000);
   BEGIN
      parameters := :SN;
      parameter1 := substr(parameters,0,10);
      parameter2 := substr(parameters,11,10);
      
      sql_txt = ''select count(1) from productDetails  where ID = :parameter1
      AND "NUMBER" = :parameter2'';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_txt USING parameter1 RETURNING INTO MSG;
   END;'; 
   
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_text USING SN RETURNING INTO MSG;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(MSG);
END;
```

However, the above can be dramatically simplified by using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO MSG
  FROM PRODUCTDETAILS
  WHERE ID = (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(SN, '[^/]+', 1, 1) FROM DUAL) AND
        "NUMBER" = (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(SN, '[^/]+', 1, 2) FROM DUAL);
```

in place of the embedded dynamic PL/SQL block. So if we create `PRODUCTDETAILS` using

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTDETAILS(ID, "NUMBER", OTHER_FIELD) AS
  SELECT 'parameter1', 'parameter2', 'DATA1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'parameter1', 'parameter2', 'DATA2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'parameter2', 'parameter3', 'DATA3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'parameter3', 'parameter4', 'DATA4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'parameter1', 'parameter2', 'DATA5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'parameter4', 'parameter2', 'DATA6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'parameter5', 'parameter6', 'DATA7' FROM DUAL
```

the above SQL will correctly return `'3'` into MSG.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e37e252162e2d1313ee0b854044faff7)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems convoluted. Have you tried this this:

```
DECLARE
    SQL_TEXT VARCHAR2(1000);
    MSG VARCHAR2(500);
    SN VARCHAR2(500) := '[your_parameter_values]';
    parameter1 VARCHAR2(50);
    parameter2 VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    parameter1 := substr(SN,0,10);
    parameter2 := substr(SN,11,10);
  
    SQL_TEXT = 'select count(1) from productDetails where ID = :p1 AND NUMBER = :p2';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_TEXT USING parameter1, paramemter2 RETURNING INTO MSG;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(MSG);
END;
```

Comment: This is incorrect; you can pass a PL/SQL anonymous block to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` as it is a single command (a single PL/SQL block).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple syntax errors including:

- `=` instead of `:=`
- `RETURNING INTO` instead of `INTO` or an `OUT` parameter.
- `NUMBER` is a keyword and cannot be used as an identifier (unless you quote it, which you haven't).
- `SUBSTR` is 1-indexed not 0-indexed (which isn't a syntax error but would cause your code to give unexpected results).

You can use:

```sql
DECLARE
    SQL_TEXT VARCHAR2(1000);
    MSG VARCHAR2(500);
    SN VARCHAR2(500) := 'parameter1/parameter2';
BEGIN

sql_text := 'DECLARE
   parameters VARCHAR2(50);
   parameter1 VARCHAR2(50);
   parameter2 VARCHAR2(50);
   sql_txt VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
   parameters := :SN;
   parameter1 := substr(parameters,1,10);
   parameter2 := substr(parameters,12,10);
    
   sql_txt := ''select count(1) from productDetails  where ID = :parameter1 AND value = :parameter2'';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_txt INTO :msg USING IN parameter1, IN parameter2;
END;'; 
   
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_text USING IN SN, OUT MSG;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(MSG);
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE productDetails ( id, value ) AS
SELECT 'parameter1', 'parameter2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d9be85cbc83868f68178dd762e6deec0)*